# SQL select statement to identify the individuals who co-authored every book ‘Bob’ has ever written

Tags: sql

Schema:

```
BID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
AID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (BID, AID)
```

Instance:

```
bid    | aid  
-------+--------
Book 1 | Ada  
Book 1 | Bob  
Book 1 | Carl  
Book 2 | Ada  
Book 2 | Bob  
Book 2 | Carl 
Book 2 | Dave  
Book 3 | Carl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag DB you're using. But you can try something like this:

```
select aid from table where bid = (select bid from table where aid='Bob')
```

- Get the book id with Bob as author
- Get all authors for those book id. It'll return Bob as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the below.

```
SELECT c.aid, c.bid
FROM table c,
        (SELECT a.bid, b.aid 
        FROM (SELECT bid, count(bid) as cbid 
                                FROM table
                                WHERE cbid > 1
                                GROUP BY bid) a 
        INNER JOIN table b 
        ON a.bid = b.bid
        WHERE b.aid = 'Bob' ) d
ON c.bid = d.bid
WHERE c.aid <> 'Bob'
```

This will return Bob's co-authors and books

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.

First, what books has bob written

```
select distinct bid from books where aid = 'bob'
```

Then, who coauthored books

```
select aid from books where aid <> 'bob' and bid in (select distinct bid from books where aid = 'bob')
```

Then, did they coauthor *all* the books

```
select aid from books where aid <> 'bob' and bid in (select distinct bid from books where aid = 'bob') 
group by aid
having count(distinct bid) = (select count(distinct bid) from books where aid = 'bob')
```